# International characters not working with SQL Sever where statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I encountered a problem with data encoding of international symbols both on my local database (SQL Server 2012) and on production (Azure SQL)

Originally it happened with Entity Framework 7 and Asp5-rc1, but I managed to reproduce it with a simple SQL queries below.

```
select Source 
from tag 
where Source like '%dzie%'
```

Returns a row with `ń` displayed properly

> dzień.txt

```
select Source 
from tag 
where Source like '%dzień%' // additional 'ń' character at the end
```

Returns **empty table**

Both SQL and Entity framework return values that look legit (with `ń`), however when I use `ń` in `where` statement, database returns no results.

However when I execute the following code i Management Studio

```
update tag 
set Source = 'dzień.txt'
where Id = 'my id'
```

Than this query (same as before)

```
select Source 
from tag 
where Source like '%dzień%' // additional 'ń' character at the end
```

This time returns a row with `ń` displayed properly

> dzień.txt

I need every character to work with the `where` statement. What should I do to make it work, especially on Azure.

Comment: What does your LINQ query look like?

Comment: @KosalaW It as simple as it can be `_context.Tags.Where(tag => tag.Source == "dzień.txt")` For demonstration i converted it to use `like` in SQLs

Comment: What is the collation of your server and that `source` column?

Comment: @rene both are SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: and if you try `where Source like N'%dzień%' `?

Comment: @rene with `N` in front it works, what does the `N` do and how to make it work with Entity Framework?

Comment: try this; `_context.Tags.Where(tag => tag.Source.Contains("dzień.txt"))` This should add `N'` to the sql query. Run MS SQL profiler as you execute the LINQ and see how it translates LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @KosalaW This works, however I have 2 concerns 1st performance 2nd it can grab more tags then I want. Is there any way to make it work with `==`?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
_context.Tags.Where(tag => tag.Source.Contains("dzień.txt"))
```

This should add `N'` to the SQL query. Run SQL Server Profiler as you execute the LINQ and see how it translates LINQ to SQL.

The other option is `Equals` operator. This is equivalent to SQL `=` operator. If you think there is a chance of having mixed case names, you can use `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`

```
_context.Tags.Where(tag => tag.Source.Equals("dzień.txt", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
```

Note the `StringComparison.CurrentCulture`.

Make sure you have an Index on `Source` field. It will improve performance significantly.

**Updated to show how to query for a collection of items**

This is one of the draw backs in EF. You cannot use LINQ to SQL for non-sql type collections. Basically any collection of items that does not exists in your SQL Server is considered as unknown to EF.

So here is an option;

```
public IENumerable<Tag> SearchTags(IENumerable<string> toBeSearchedTags)
{
    List<Tag> availableTags = new List<Tag>();

    foreach(var stag in toBeSearchedTags)
    {
       var availableTag = _context.Tags.FirstOrdefault(tag => tag.Source.Equals(stag, StringComparison.CurrentCulture)) 

       if(availableTag != null)
       {
          availableTags.Add(availableTag);
       }
    }

    return availableTags;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Actually I have to run this query against a collection of file names, like so: `_context.Tags.Where(tag => files.Contains(tag.Source))` Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: Actually Contains method is implemented by EF, but I cannot make is use `N` prefix. What you suggested for collections handling is very inefficient. I guess I'll have to go with raw SQL this time :)

Comment: You can use stored procedures in EF. For any complex search functionalities, it's far more efficient to use SPs rather than depend on EF purely (like what I have suggested above). So knowledge in SQL is very relevant, no matter what ORM is used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that the *ń* is a Unicode character, and your string literal *'%dzień%'* is not marked as Unicode string. Unicode strings are marked by the `N''` prefix.

To test this in Management Studio, simply run

```
select 'dzień'
```

which results in `dzien`. If you change the string to Unicode,

```
select N'dzień'
```

you get `dzień`.

Note that the `N''`-notation is a [feature of T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx), and need not be distinguished in a profiler or other logging.

Change your query to

```
select Source 
from tag 
where Source like N'%dzień%'
```

and you should see the desired result.

Comment: The question is not really about sql. OP needs help with LINQ